# Increment Text on Drawing Circles (List of)

Tags: vb.net, gdi

I am developing a target software and I need to keep track of shots on the picturebox using drawstring and a number by the circle.  My issue is that every circle I draw, all the numbers on the previous circle update to the same (i.e. 4 circles all have "4", draw another and they all update to "5", etc.).

I have attached an image and my code:
[image]

Here's the code:

```
Public Class TargetAnalysis
Dim n As Integer = 0
Dim zoomPct As Decimal = 1

Dim shotList As New List(Of Point)
Dim scaleList As New List(Of Point)
Dim poaList As New List(Of Point)
Dim ShotCount As New List(Of Point)

Private Sub mPictureBox_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles mPictureBox.MouseClick
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then

      If shotFlag = True Then
            n += 1
            _shotX = e.X
            _shotY = e.Y


            shotList.Add(New Point(_shotX, _shotY))
            ShotCount.Add(New Point(_shotX, _shotY))

            shotDist = Math.Sqrt((_shotX - _poaX) ^ 2 + (_shotY - _poaY) ^ 2)
            Me.lbDataPoints.Items.Insert(shotList.Count - 1, "SHOT - " &
                FormatNumber(shotDist * pLineDist(), 2) & " in.")
            Me.txtShotCount.EditValue = shotList.Count

            mPictureBox.Refresh()

        End If
    end if
End Sub

Private Sub mPictureBox_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles mPictureBox.Paint


    'SHOT number
    For Each s As Point In ShotCount
        Dim calRad As Decimal = cboCaliber.EditValue / pLineDist() / 2

        Dim _shot As New ShotCount(e.Graphics, New Point(s.X + calRad, s.Y + calRad), cboCaliber.EditValue / pLineDist() / 2,
                                   "Consolas", FormatNumber((Math.Sqrt((s.X - _poaX) ^ 2 + (s.Y - _poaY) ^ 2)) *
                                    pLineDist(), 2) & "in")
    Next

end sub
```

This code does not increment, but does show and persist the distances

Comment: The Bullet should be a class. Then, store each bullet in a `List(Of T)`. As they move you update their location so then you paint each bullet at it's correct location. When they leave the working area delete them from the list.

Comment: Each bullet is in a class, are you saying move the text string to its own class as well?  Thanks

Comment: I added a BulletNo class to handle the Text and now I call:   For Each t As Integer In _shotNo
            Dim _shot As New BulletNo(e.Graphics, _shotX, _shotY, n, "Consolas")
        Next.  This shows the count, but deletes the other shot text strings.

Comment: The Bullet class should not be drawing, just holding values. The form paints them based on their values.

Comment: Thanks. I'll make the change and see if I can get it working properly.

Comment: I'm still dealing with the the text repainting to the same number.

Comment: Did you update the code above to reflect your latest attempt?

Comment: Yes, now the previous numbers disappear.  I need the previous numbers to show.

Comment: Also, I can draw the coordinates at each "shot" and persist them by using the s.tostring from the shotlist.  It seems trying to increment a value outside of that list updates them all, no matter how I have the code written currently. Thanks.

Comment: In your code you are still painting in the Bullet class, not correct. Paint in the form's Paint event. In your loop you are creating new bullets, rather you should just be painting them - then the names would not get overwritten.

Comment: Can you throw me some sample code. I am apparently not getting this. I moved the drawing code to the paint event and the previous shotno just disappears. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I also just reread your other post and I did not update he code above, but did update mine. It's been a long few days :)

Comment: It is hard to give an example since I do not know what elements are need to be stored in the bullet class. I can image these: bulletNumber, Image, Point. I would also imagine some event creates a new bullet that is added to a class collection of them(`List(of Bullet)`). To start a new canvas simple clear the List. In the paint event you simply iterate the bullets in the List and paint based on their properties. Nothing should be disappearing if done correctly. Please update your code as to where you are.

Comment: I updated the code.  This does not increment the shot number, but does persist the shot distance at each shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Class TargetAnalysis

    Dim shotList As New List(Of Point)
    Dim shotFlag As Boolean

    Private Function ShotDistance(ByVal shot As Point) As Double
        ' _poaX and _poaY are the origin?
        Return Math.Sqrt((shot.X - _poaX) ^ 2 + (shot.Y - _poaY) ^ 2) * pLineDist()
    End Function

    Private Sub mPictureBox_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles mPictureBox.MouseClick
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left AndAlso shotFlag Then
            Dim shot As New Point(e.X, e.Y)
            shotList.Add(shot)            
            shotDist = ShotDistance(shot)

            Me.lbDataPoints.Items.Insert(shotList.Count - 1, String.Format("SHOT - {0:N2} in.", shotDist))

            Me.txtShotCount.EditValue = shotList.Count
            mPictureBox.Refresh()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub mPictureBox_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles mPictureBox.Paint
        Dim calRad As Decimal = cboCaliber.EditValue / pLineDist() / 2

        For i As Integer = 0 To shotList.Count - 1
            Dim shot As Point = shotList(i)
            Dim dist As Double = ShotDistance(shot)
            Dim labelLoc As New Point(shot.X + calRad, shot.Y + calRad)
            Dim text As String = String.Format("Shot {0} - {1:N2} in.", i + 1, dist)

            DrawShotLabel(e.Graphics, text, labelLoc)
        Next i           
    End Sub

    Private Sub DrawShotLabel(g As Graphics, label As String, location As Point)
        Dim consolas As New Font("Consolas", 8)
        Dim textSize As Size = g.MeasureString(label, consolas).ToSize()
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, New Rectangle(location, textSize))
        g.DrawString(label, consolas, Brushes.Black, location)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks Joel. I will try this approach.

Comment: Worked perfect.  I did make a few edits, but nothing major.  Thanks!